# AngularJS 1.2.0 $resource response is empty

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I'm using AngularJS 1.2.0. 
When I'm calling a webservice with $resouce the response variable is always empty. The webservice is called correctly and the webservice is sending the result to the browser. The problem is that (callback(response){}) response is always empty.

```
angular.module('app').factory('geoCoding',['$resource', function ($resource) {
return $resource('http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address', {key: getGeoKey()}, {
    locate: {method: 'GET', isArray: false}
});
}]);

$scope.getLocations = function (locationName) {
    return geoCoding.locate({location: locationName}).$promise.then(
      function (response) {
        log.log('response ', response);
        if (response && response.data && response.data.results && response.data.results[0]) {

          var locations = [];

          response.data.results[0].locations.forEach(function (location) {
            locations.push({name: geoUtils.location2String(location), location: location});
          });

          return locations;
        } else {
          return {};
        }

      }, function (error) {
        log.error('Locations Query error: ', error);
      });
  };
```

Comment: also having this issue, totally non-obvious solutions :(

Comment: you probably need to add `.json` to the end of your URL.  This changed between 1.0 and 1.1x/1.2x.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few different approaches using 1.2.0rc1.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);
app.factory('geoCoding',['$resource', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('response.json', {key: 123}, {
    locate: {method: 'GET', isArray: false}
  });
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,geoCoding){
  // bind it directly to the async result
  $scope.locations = geoCoding.locate({location: "a location"});

  // use a function to trigger the request
  $scope.getLocations = function () {
    $scope.resp = geoCoding.locate({location: "a location"});
  };

  // use a function to trigger the request using the promise
  $scope.getLocationsAlt = function() {
    geoCoding.locate({location: "a location"}).$promise.then(function(response){
      $scope.respAlt = response;
    }, angular.noop);
  };
});
```

**Updated based on comment**

It looks like the problem you are facing is that the data is coming back in an unexpected format. Here is what the updated code would look like (http://plnkr.co/edit/xzZHvm?p=preview):

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);
app.factory('geoCoding',['$resource', '$http', '$log', function ($resource, $http, $log) {
  return $resource('http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address', {}, {
    locate: {method: 'GET', isArray: true, transformResponse: $http.defaults.transformResponse.concat(function(data, headersGetter) {
      // probably be better if you examined the results in here
      $log.info(data.results[0]);
      return data.results[0].locations;
    })}
  });
}]);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $log, geoCoding){
  $scope.locations = geoCoding.locate({location: "Dallas, TX"});
});
```

Comment: this also doesn't work with remote resources, example: http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address

Comment: aha... it looks like you need to transform the response. I will update my answer.

Comment: awesome, i don't know why it didn't work with your original answer (the bareResponse was blank for remote resources) but this version works great!

Comment: +1 I was using a call that returned only headers, and by extracting the relevant header from the header in the transformResponse worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a plunker which shows $resource callbacks being logged working with similar code to yours here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/o7hjbd3H2vl2LuHBjI8O?p=preview

When I used the URL you have above I got an ORIGIN error and the request wasn't being made successfully, so I've demonstrated with a response.json stub instead.

Comment: With Angular 1.0.7 everything is working. The problem is with Version 1.2.0!

Comment: does not work with a non-local resource, as per his example: http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address

Comment: and if you complain about XSS, use firefox which allows it, still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all of you for the help, and probably I'm saying the same thing, but the truth is, I can't do it right yet. I fixed my errors and at this moment, my code doesn't have errors but all my page disappeared. I don't understand if I am opening the api already or simply it's not working. I'll send my .js code to create a little discussion about it.

Thanks for your help.

'use strict';

angular.module('SiteApp', [])
.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.user = {username: '', password: ''};

```
$scope.go = function() {
    $http.jsonp('http://beta.cloogy.com:6969/api/1.0', {
          data : {
            User: user.username,
            Password: user.password
          }
      })
    .success(function (data) {
      $scope.$parent.image = data;
      $location.path('/Index'); //this is a simply second view to test
    })
    .error(function (data) {
      $scope.msg="Error loading the page!";
    });
}
```

}
]);