# "GET"ting AngularJS resource in MSIE 9 returns empty array

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, internet-explorer

## Problem

When using the `GET` request from a `$resource`, the response on success is an empty array in Microsoft Internet Explorer 9 only.

### Tests

Scenarios of Success:

- Using FF or Chrome, the `GET` request returns an array of data in both development and local environments.
- IE9 accessing a **local** server, the "GET" request returns an array of data.

Scenario of failure:

- IE9 accessing the **development** server, an empty array is returned.

Debugging steps:

- In IE9 accessing the **development** server:

  - typing in the URL to the REST API will successfully return an array of data. ✓
  - stepping through the debugger verifies that the data sent to the server are numbers and of the correct value. ✓
  - POSTing data to another $resource works fine - data is persisted in the database and is correct. ✓
  - stepping through the debugger shows an empty array in the success method. ✗

### Results

- REST API is working since a direct request returns data
- Angular should be working, since results are returned in FF and Chrome

### Questions

- Is there any other tips to debug this issue?
- What could be the cause of this?
- Is there any IE9 specific issues with Ajax requests?

### Possible Related Resources

- [AngularJS 1.2.0 $resource response is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548114/angularjs-1-2-0-resource-response-is-empty) - in my case, I get a response, it's just an empty array
- [AngularJS factory http returns empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336987/angularjs-factory-http-returns-empty) - current issue is IE9 only

### Code

#### Resource

```
var AnswerSetBySubjectByForm = function($resource) {
    return $resource('/rest/answerset/subject/:idSubject/form/:idForm',
            { idSubject : '@idSubject', idForm : '@idForm'},
            {'get' : {method:'GET', isArray:true}}
        );
};
```

#### Controller

```
var AnswerSetController = function($scope, AnswerSetBySubjectByForm) {

...

  $scope.$on('loadAnswerSets', function(e, idSubject, idForm) {
    if (angular.isNumber(idSubject) && angular.isNumber(idForm)) {
      AnswerSetBySubjectByForm.get({ 
        idSubject : idSubject, 
        idForm : idForm
      }, function(answerSets) {
        /* answerSets is an empty array in IE9 only */
        $scope.answerSets = angular.copy(answerSets);
      });
    }
  });

...
```

#### Application

```
...

app                
  .factory('AnswerSetBySubjectByForm', 
        ['$resource', AnswerSetBySubjectByForm])
  .controller('AnswerSetController', 
        ['$scope', 'AnswerSetBySubjectByForm', AnswerSetController])

...
```

Any help in debugging this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AJAX problem in IE9?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996702/ajax-problem-in-ie9)

Comment: Turns out the problem was caching in MSIE9. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this in your angular code to prevent GET requests being cached

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    //Disable caching and make sure the call is made for each GET request.
    //Especially for IE, disable ajax get request caching
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get || {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
}]);
```

Comment: Quick question, would you know if there's a difference between setting the headers at the server vs. setting the headers at the client? Is there a preference for choosing one over the other in terms of security and/or performance?

Comment: I don't think it matters either way.