# IE9 resource returing array of char instead of JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, internet-explorer-9, ngresource

I'm having a rating system with an API to handle the ratings. On the `Get` method is the following code:

```
public JToken Get(string vid) {
    JToken result = null;

    var status = new {
        Rating = 100,
        UserRated = true
    };
    result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(status);


    return result;
}
```

and in my service I do:

```
factory('Rating', ['$resource',
function ($resource) {
    var src = config.getValue("api.rating");
    return $resource(src, {}, {
        get: {
            method: 'GET',
            withCredentials: true,
            responseType: 'json'
        }
    });
}])
```

in Firefox and Chrome this works fine when I do:

```
Rating.get({ vid: $scope.video.Id }, function (res) {
          $scope.videoRating = res.Rating;
}
```

but in IE9 it gets an array of char from the string that is being returned.
Can someone tell me what's going on, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Try clearing your cache: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871236/getting-angularjs-resource-in-msie-9-returns-empty-array

Comment: @alex, tried it, no change in result

Comment: If you have developer tool check network and check the reponse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by doing the following:

```
public JObject Get(string vid) {
    String result;

    var status = new {
        Rating = 100,
        UserRated = true
    };
    result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(status);


    return JObject.Parse(result);
}
```

seems there was a problem with the Jtoken, and by doing an explicit parse to `JObject` it ended up working just fine